# Using VB, Delphi to create GUI for Python script

Tags: python, visual-studio, vba, user-interface

I have some python script working with win32api, and I want to create some GUI. I think, that VisualStudio with VB be good for that, but maybe someone on StackOverflow already do such thing? I prefer to do end-aplication (End user don't have libs or python etc)

Any advise...

Comment: For distribution you can look at http://www.py2exe.org/

Comment: If you are specifically targeting Windows, have you considered using IronPython? This would allow you to use WPF, for which there's designer support in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

there are some GUI designers for python: 
IN UBUNTU: 
 1st  Glade: 
      here is a tutorial  http://www.micahcarrick.com/gtk-glade-tutorial-part-1.html

2   Quickly

```
install : 
    sudo apt-get install quickly
    quickly create ubuntu-application hello-world    
    cd hello-world/
     here is tutorial : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Quickly
```

In windows : 
  PyQt  : 
       full tutorial  : http://talk.maemo.org/showthread.php?t=43663

Answer (score 0):

[Python for Delphi](http://code.google.com/p/python4delphi/) will allow you to embed a Python interpreter in a Delphi application. Not sure how up-to-date it's been kept though.